# How to reference 2 tables with address information and no common key

Tags: sql, ms-access, foreign-keys

I'm very new to databases and to SQL as well. I am currently running SQL queries on MS Access until our SQL Server gets set up.

I have 2 datasets, 1 which has work information and location of the work, the other has length and width of roadways which I would like to reference. I am trying to get these 2 to talk.

My work dataset has address in 3 columns "On/From/To" format. E.g. on main street, from park place to broadway. I am trying to reference the only similar column in the other dataset, which would correspond with my "on" street.

These 2 datasets have no common keys and the primary key is autonumbered and indexed. These are both large datasets.

How do I proceed to get these 2 datasets to speak?

Comment: Welcoem to SO. Please can you share the SQL that you have tried so far.

Comment: What columns are available in the second dataset, with length and width of roadways? It sounds like you're looking for a join, but depending on the what fields are available changes what might be used to match them. Any code you've attempted so far will be helpful as well.

Comment: So the data in both ON fields is consistent for spelling between tables? Is ON in OTHER db unique? Have you tried joining with the ON fields? ON is a reserved word. Should not use reserved words as names for anything. Doesn't hurt to provide table names as well as field names. If there is no common data, how would you expect them to 'communicate'?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay everyone, had some things come up the past few weeks and was unavailable.

Thanks for the replys and for being gentle with such a noobie as myself.

What I was looking for was an Intersect, which Access VBA does not have, and found a way to do so.

I did an inner join on my address field with the other tables address field and was able to accomplish my very simple query.

Appreciate all the help